# Android Studio - cannot resolve method getSupportFragment()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

Below is my code in DrawerItemClickListener.java. The getFragmentManager() and getActionBar() are on red and says cannot resolve method. How can i fix this?

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

```
private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectItem(position);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new CreateFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ReadFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new HelpFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: both are method of `(Fragment)Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((YourFragmentActivity)activity).getFragmentManager();
```

instead of

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try: `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are in `Activity`.
Maybe it will help